# Selected Link need to be highlight

Tags: html, css, performance

I have set of links, on click of the link I try to add background color to it .
its working partially but previously highlighted value is not getting removed for next click. please check my code and let me know, what went wrong..thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/prabunivas/6KN3L/

### HTML

```
<div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="4">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="5">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
ul li {
    padding: 5px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu a').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its probably better to manage your "selected" attributes as a separate class, then it becomes a matter of using JQuery to either [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) or [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) as required - [as seen in this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6KN3L/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    $(".selected").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});                              
});
```

This means you can progressively add more functionality to the `selected` class without having to manage turning on or off additional styles.

```
.selected {
    background-color:red;
    color: green;
    border-color:blue;
   /* etc... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KN3L/4/)

You need to reset the background-color for the links before applying it to another one:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu a').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#menu a').css('background-color','none');
        $(this).css('background-color','red')
    });                              
});
```

Comment: @SPN please if you don't have any other question mark it as solved :)